# UI Elements (e.g. MapSettingControl) disappearing on Safari 13

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, safari, here-api

The problem is that on Safari 13 some elements are not shown in the order (z-index) as implemented. The element however is functioning as expected, so the zoom works (if you know where located) but the control is invisible. This is working OK on other devices, e.g. Safari 13 on Mac or ios12, ...

The heremap is an element of the Ionic home.page and includes a here-map component. The here-map component initialises the MapControlElements.

Already tried to set here-map with an z-index of, e.g. 90, and set the MapSettingsControl to 99. However, it remains staying always on top. Tried to set in CSS, addClass and direct setting the HTML element of the MapControlSetting. I tried to add a customised control and adding the CSS class. No Luck so far.

```
    **HTML component**
     <div #map class="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    **CSS component**
    .map {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color:primary
    }

   .btnOnTop {
      position: absolute; 
      z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
   }

    **here-component**
    @ViewChild("map",{static: true})public mapElement: ElementRef;

    this.mapUI.getControl("mapsettings").addClass("btnOnTop"); 

    or

    this.mapUI.getElement().style.zIndex = 999;
```

I'd like having the Control elements visible at the given alignment, e.g. bottom-right but on Safari and Chrome on Safari 13 it is disappearing.

Comment: Can you please provide a version of your code so we can try to reproduce on our side?

Comment: It simply happens whenever I add some ionic items onto the map as an overlay. Then you lose the here UI elements, however, you can use them if you know where these are located. I am using an iPhone 6S with ios13.2.3. How should I provide you with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting index using below method :

```
public PositionIndicator setZIndex(int index)
```

Set the Z index of the position indicator. The default Z-Index is currently the max value supported.

**Parameters:**

index - A new z-index value for the MapObject, a 16-bit int within the range of [0..65535]
Returns:
PositionIndicator this object for method chaining.

Refer below documentation, also upgrade to the latest android version.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/PositionIndicator.html#setZIndex-int-